# Scikit-Learn custom Evaluation scorer Throwing Error for shape mismatch, where requested shape isnt the shape of input variables

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to create a custom evaluation scorer in scikit-learn which I can use to get eval scores for different regressors.

Here is the custom evaluation function:

```
def eval_func(y_true, y_pred):
  return float(max(0,100*r2_score(y_true , y_pred)))
```

Definition for custom scorer

```
cust_scorer = make_scorer(eval_func, greater_is_better=True)
```

I am using the above in the following function

```
def regression_model(model, data, predictors,outcome):
  #Fit the model:
  #features = data.drop(columns=[outcome])
  features = data[predictors]
  print(features.shape)
  
  target = data[outcome].to_numpy().reshape(-1,1)
  print(target.shape)
  model.fit(features,target)
  
  #Make predictions on training set:
  predictions = model.predict(features)

  print(predictions.shape)
  
  #Print accuracy
  accuracy = cust_scorer(model,predictions,target)
  print ("Eval_metric : %s" % "{0:.3%}".format(accuracy))
#Perform k-fold cross-validation with 5 folds
  kf = KFold(data.shape[0], n_folds=5)
  error = []
  for train, test in kf:
    # Filter training data
    train_predictors = (features.iloc[train,:])
    
    # The target we're using to train the algorithm.
    train_target = target.iloc[train]
    
    # Training the algorithm using the predictors and target.
    model.fit(train_predictors, train_target)
    
    #Record error from each cross-validation run
    error.append(cust_scorer(model,features.iloc[test,:], target.iloc[test]))
 
  print ("Cross-Validation Score : %s" % "{0:.3%}".format(np.mean(error)))
```

I get the following error on the line where i call the custom scorer to get accuracy

```
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 57 is different from 1)
```

The traceback:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-206-fdf6c0030d91> in <module>()
     76 
     77 predictors = list(set(train_data.columns).difference({target_col}))
---> 78 regression_model(lr,train_data,predictors,target_col)
     79 # features = train_data[predictors].values
     80 # # print(features.shape)

<ipython-input-206-fdf6c0030d91> in regression_model(model, data, predictors, outcome)
     34 
     35   #Print accuracy
---> 36   accuracy = cust_scorer(model,predictions,target)
     37   print ("Eval_metric : %s" % "{0:.3%}".format(accuracy))
     38 #Perform k-fold cross-validation with 5 folds

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py in __call__(self, estimator, X, y_true, sample_weight)
    167                           stacklevel=2)
    168         return self._score(partial(_cached_call, None), estimator, X, y_true,
--> 169                            sample_weight=sample_weight)
    170 
    171     def _factory_args(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py in _score(self, method_caller, estimator, X, y_true, sample_weight)
    203         """
    204 
--> 205         y_pred = method_caller(estimator, "predict", X)
    206         if sample_weight is not None:
    207             return self._sign * self._score_func(y_true, y_pred,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py in _cached_call(cache, estimator, method, *args, **kwargs)
     50     """Call estimator with method and args and kwargs."""
     51     if cache is None:
---> 52         return getattr(estimator, method)(*args, **kwargs)
     53 
     54     try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py in predict(self, X)
    223             Returns predicted values.
    224         """
--> 225         return self._decision_function(X)
    226 
    227     _preprocess_data = staticmethod(_preprocess_data)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py in _decision_function(self, X)
    207         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])
    208         return safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,
--> 209                                dense_output=True) + self.intercept_
    210 
    211     def predict(self, X):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py in safe_sparse_dot(a, b, dense_output)
    149             ret = np.dot(a, b)
    150     else:
--> 151         ret = a @ b
    152 
    153     if (sparse.issparse(a) and sparse.issparse(b)
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 57 is different from 1)
```

According to the error , atleast one of the inputs to the scorer should have shape with any dimension to be 57 (where 57 is the number of input features of data, and one output feature).

But both inputs to Scorer are of dimensions `(22939, 1)`

I tried passing the 2 inputs of scorer directly to my eval function, and it is giving me proper results, only when i pass it through the scorer, I am getting this issue.

I dont understand how the `57` as a dimension came into picture for inputs with different shape, and what to do about it.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Edit 1: To generate data to test this, you can create a random np array of dimension `(22939, 58)`, convert it to DataFrame, with last column being the `outcome` column and rest being predictors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved.

I Was passing predictions as 1st input to the scorer object , while ideally it should be the Feature Vector.

so `Scorer(model, feature, label)` is the right format. Internally Sklearn will pass the feature through the model to get predictions and then pass those through custom eval function.